# How do I connect a Windows XP Pro and Ubuntu 12.04 together over the network

Tags: networking, windows-xp

How do I connect a Windows XP Pro and Ubuntu 12.04 together over the network.

I used the networking wizard in Windows to create a networking setup.  I am not sure I did it right, so maybe someone can help me setup Windows networking properly.

And then can you tell me how to connect to that Windows network from Ubuntu 12.04.

And I have another box that that is running Openbox with Xfe and I would like to know how to connect that box also.

So I need to connect an Ubuntu 12.04 box and an Ubuntu server box running openbox with Xfe.

Thanks so much for your help as I've been pulling my hair out.

Comment: have a look at [this blog post](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/03/configure-samba-sharing-between-ubuntu.html). The screenshots are from an older version of Ubuntu, but the procedure is exactly the same.

Comment: OK, I'll try that tutorial later today and report back.